# listview is not showing all of the data

Tags: android, android-listview

this is my source code; listview is not showing the "status". Rest of the data is visible' i don't know where is the problem. kindly help me it's been a while i'm trying to solve this issue. it's the application which sends the email and receives as well,and this is the mailbox source code. in mail box it should show Status,From,Expert,Subject,Price.

```
public class MailBox extends ListActivity {
    String userName;
    ListView MailList;
    //////contact JSonArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;
    String x;
    private static final String Status="a";
    String StatusVal="";
    private static final String From="b";
    String FromVal;
    private static final String Expert="c";
    String ExpertVal;
    private static final String Subject="d";
    private static final String Price="e";
    String SubjectVal;
     // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "list";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "mail_ID";
    private static final String TAG_STATUS = "mail_status";
    private static final String TAG_FROM_ID= "fromID";
    private static final String TAG_TO_ID= "toID";
    private static final String TAG_QUESTION= "questionid";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE= "mail_price";
     String xVal="";
     String arr[];
     Handler handler;
      // Hashmap for ListView
     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
     ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mail_box);
        MailList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        final Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(b!=null)
        {
        userName=b.getString("userName");
        }


        handler = new Handler();
        starttask();
    }
    public void starttask()
    {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"" , "Logging In");
         Thread thread = new Thread() {
             public void run () {
             String url = "http://onlinesolutionproviders.com/apiosp.php?student_inbox=1&client_login_id="+userName;
                // Creating JSON Parser object   
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

         HttpContext httpContext= new BasicHttpContext();
        try {
            contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
            for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
              JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
              String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
              String name = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
              String fromid = c.getString(TAG_FROM_ID); 
              String toid = c.getString(TAG_TO_ID);
              String subject = c.getString(TAG_QUESTION); 
              String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE); 
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_STATUS, name);//status
                map.put(TAG_FROM_ID, fromid);//from id
                map.put(TAG_TO_ID, toid);//expert name
                map.put(TAG_QUESTION, subject);//subject
                map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);//price
                String URL="http://onlinesolutionproviders.com/apiosp.php?client_email_subject=1&client_login_id="+userName+"&to_id="
                        +toid+"&from_id="+fromid+"&questionid="+id+"&status="+name;
                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse    
                Log.d("url mail box",URL);


                 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);

             try
             {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, httpContext);
                HttpEntity hte=response.getEntity();
                InputStream is= hte.getContent();
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
                String line=null;
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "");
                }
                is.close();
                 x= String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));

                Scanner scan= new Scanner(x);

                arr= new String[5];
                int j=0;
                while(scan.hasNextLine())
                {
                    arr[j]=scan.nextLine();
                    j++;
                }
                 map.put(Status, arr[0]);
                 map.put(From, arr[1]);
                 map.put(Expert, arr[2]);
                 map.put(Subject, arr[3]);       
                map.put(Price, arr[4]);   
             }
             catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OOps! Something went wrong. Restart the Application" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OOps! Something went wrong. Restart the Application" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                contactList.add(map);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 updateUI();
                 progressDialog.dismiss();



                                }
                            });

                        }

                    };

                    thread.start();


       }
     private void updateUI () {
         SpecialAdapter adapter = new SpecialAdapter(MailBox.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item_mailbox,
                    new String[] { TAG_ID, Status, From, Expert, Subject, Price, TAG_FROM_ID,TAG_TO_ID,TAG_QUESTION, TAG_STATUS }, new int[] {
                           R.id.eID ,R.id.status_heading,  R.id.expert_heading,R.id.eexpert_heading, R.id.subject_heading, R.id.price_heading,
                           R.id.fromid, R.id.toid,R.id.question,R.id.statusid}); 
          setListAdapter(adapter);
          ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    /* for(int a = 0; a < parent.getChildCount(); a++)
                     {
                         parent.getChildAt(a).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                     }

                     view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);*/
                    String mailid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.eID)).getText().toString();
                    String fromid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fromid)).getText().toString();
                    String toid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.toid)).getText().toString();
                    String question = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.question)).getText().toString();
                    String status = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status_heading)).getText().toString();
                    String pricetosend = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price_heading)).getText().toString();
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MailBoxDetail.class);
                    in.putExtra("mailid", mailid);
                    in.putExtra("fromid", fromid);
                    in.putExtra("toid", toid);
                    in.putExtra("question", question);
                    in.putExtra("userName", userName);
                    in.putExtra("status", status);
                    in.putExtra("pricetosend", pricetosend);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            });
    }
```

this is the code for specialAdapter

```
package com.OSP.client;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    private int[] colors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#D8D8D8") };

        public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, items, resource, from, to);
        }

    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
          int colorPos = position % colors.length;
          view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
          return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please provide code of `SpecialAdapter`

Comment: you should definitely indent and organize your code more !

Comment: @Nezam: tnx for the response. i have attached the code kindly check now

Comment: are you using custom xml layout for each row of the listview?

Comment: @Yume117 actually i have just joined the new company and this code is written by the last developer and i'm trying to organize and solve the problim....

Comment: if there is no error and the data isn't showing on status, then there must be an issu retrieving the data (do some debug/log) or the view where the data is used is not retrieved correctly. Did you check this part :  new String[] { TAG_ID, Status, From, Expert, Subject, Price, TAG_FROM_ID,TAG_TO_ID,TAG_QUESTION, TAG_STATUS }, new int[] {
                           R.id.eID ,R.id.status_heading,  R.id.expert_heading,R.id.eexpert_heading, R.id.subject_heading, R.id.price_heading,
                           R.id.fromid, R.id.toid,R.id.question,R.id.statusid});

Answer (score 0):

I think you're new to Android development.

You need to write the custom implementation of those `row.xml` row layouts yourself in the `getView` method of `SpecialAdapter`.You can refer this code below to make something of your own (quite simple):

```
@Override
    public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {

        /* create a new view of my layout and inflate it in the row */
        convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );

        /* Extract the city's object to show */
        City city = getItem( position );

        /* Take the TextView from layout and set the city's name */
        TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cityName);
        txtName.setText(city.getName());

        /* Take the TextView from layout and set the city's wiki link */
        TextView txtWiki = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cityLinkWiki);
        txtWiki.setText(city.getUrlWiki());

        /* Take the ImageView from layout and set the city's image */
        ImageView imageCity = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageCity);
        String uri = "drawable/" + city.getImage();
        int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
        Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        imageCity.setImageDrawable(image);
        return convertView;
    }
```

You should go through the `Getting Started` portions of [`developer.android.com`](http://developer.android.com).But this [`tutorial`](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/) would get you started quicker.

Comment: yes i m new in API related project, kidly tell me how to apply your code... in my special adapter there is list view which i have already generated.. there is no text or image view, how to write it accurately or is there any problem in special adapter..?